# data-pre rails 3 + jquery tokeninput + acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on, jquery-tokeninput

i am developing an application that works with tags, to do so, i am using jquery tokeninput and acts_as_taggable_on, but when save some changes, the tags start to show there id number instead of name also when save again the existing tags again with the number as the name.

i think that is a data-pre error or a mapping error.

in my view:

```
= form_for @profile, :html=> {:class => 'custom'} do |f|
= f.text_field :skill_list, :id => "profile_skills", "data-pre" => @profile.skills.to_json
```

controller:

```
def skills
query = params[:q]
if query[-1,1] == " "
  query = query.gsub(" ", "")
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find_or_create_by_name(query)
end

@skills = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
@skills = @skills.select { |v| v.name =~ /#{query}/i }
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @skills.map{|t| {:id => t.name, :name => t.name }}}
end
```

end

application.js:

```
$(function(){ 
$(document).foundation(); 
$("#profile_skills").tokenInput("/profiles/skills.json", {
    prePopulate:       $("#profile#skills").data("pre"),
    preventDuplicates: true,
    hintText:          "Ingresa alguna habilidad",
    noResultsText:     "No se encontraron tags, crea uno con espacio",
    searchingText:     "Buscando...",
    animateDropdown:   true,
    theme: 'facebook'
```

});
});

routes:

```
get "profiles/skills" => "profiles#skills", :as => :profiles_skills
```